# Rails 3 assocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to get the user_id of the user that is logged in. So a user will create a blog post and it will capture the id of the user when creating the blog post.

I know how to do this using nested resources but how can I get the user_id when creating a new blog post without nested resources?

the routes would look like this

```
resources :blogs
```

I also tried adding hidden field to blog form _blog.html.erb

```
<%= f.hidden_field :site_id, :value => @blog.site_id %>
```

The association is set up correctly I am just trying to see how I can get the user_id without nested resources. Any suggestions?

Comment: question is somewhat misleading or incomplete. how does user_id related to nested resources?

Comment: If I were to create a nested resource using sites and blogs then I could get the user_id by updating blogs controller to include site params.

Comment: its not about another way, its how you want it. how you will going to get user_id from site params, you haven't explained that inside your question?

Comment: another thing ur question title is also wrong ..it predicts question is related to association but its not..question is how to get logged in user inside controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using devise/authlogic for authentication then you can easily get user_id using `current_user` method provided

Comment: Is this the only way or preferred? I know how to do it this way I were just wondering if there was another way, if not then I am ok.

Comment: you wrote `var end = "98.343" +"44.323243243";` that should be like -
`var end = new google.maps.LatLng("98.343", "44.323243243");`

Comment: What if I want the current_site that the user owns? How can I write my private method? I am using devise so I can use the `current_user` method but how can I find the user's current site_id?

Comment: define `current_site` as private method that will return site associated with current_user

Answer (score 3):

Pull the user id off the currently logged in user in the BlogsController#create method.

Example (Note that how you access the user_id will depend on how you're doing authentication)

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new params[:blog]
    @blog.user_id = current_user.id
    if @blog.save
      ...
    end
  end
end
```